# Sendmail does not receive e-mails from outside

Tags: email, unix, centos

have a VPS running CentOs 5.1 64bit with ISPManager panel.
dovecot-1.0.7-7.el5 is used in conjunction with sendmail.

I can send e-mails to outside (sendmail works), can send and receive e-mails locally (from server itself), but I don't receive ones sent from outside (like my gmail account).

Get reports from google as follows:

```
Technical details of temporary failure: 
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7720 
[mail.mydomain.com. (10): Connection refused]
[mail.mydomain.com. (20): Connection refused]
```

Any ideas?
P.S. I can ping mail.mydomain.com. I can access mailboxes via POP3/IMAP.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are two MX records created with ISPManager (mail)

Answer (score 0):

First double check how your MX'es are set: host -t mx yourdomain.com.
And then check if you can telnet mail.yourdomain.com 25 from outside to see if you can connect to SMTP port fine.

It looks to me like MTA is binded to localhost or you have some firewall blocking SMTP access.